# Register new PHP Handler clipath

Tags: error-handling, plesk

I need to install php 6.5 for an old project.

I register the new Handler in Plesk:

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/php_handler --add -id 6.5.6 -displayname 6.5.6 -path /usr/local/php65/bin/php-cgi -phpini /usr/local/php65/php.ini -type fastcgi
```

And I get this error message:

```
Required option -clipath is not set
```

A search provides no information about `-clipath`.

Comment: `-phpini /usr/local/php65/php.ini -clipath <path to php binary>` on my machine it would be `-clipath "F:\xampp\php\php.exe"` for you I assume it would be `-clipath /usr/local/php65/php.exe`

Comment: I have linux machine, there is no exe and no other files for start php

Comment: What do you mean by "PHP 6.5"? Such a version never existed.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use php on Plesk. You should be asking your question in [Plesk's support forums](https://talk.plesk.com/) or [Plesk Support](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us)

The answer could be:

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/php_handler --add -id 6.5.6 -displayname 6.5.6 -path /usr/local/php65/bin/php-cgi -phpini /usr/local/php65/php.ini -type cgi -clipath /usr/local/php65/bin/php
```

If not ask Plesk support: `What is my path to the PHP binary?`

They are going to want to know if you are using `Plesk Onyx for Linux` or `Plesk Obsidian for Linux`.

[Plesk PHP Management](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/administrator-guide/web-hosting/php-management.70668/)

1. [Installing PHP](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/administrator-guide/web-hosting/php-management/installing-php.75153/)
2. [Configuring PHP Handlers](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/administrator-guide/web-hosting/php-management/configuring-php-handlers.75149/)
3. [PHP Extensions and Settings](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/administrator-guide/web-hosting/php-management/php-extensions-and-settings.75811/)

Comment: The issue is solved :

/usr/local/psa/bin/php_handler --add -id 6.5.6 -displayname 6.5.6 -path /usr/local/php65/bin/php-cgi -phpini /usr/local/php65/php.ini -type cgi -clipath /usr/local/php65/bin/php

Comment: @mar Updated my answer.